# Why can't I enter the admin interface in django after customizing the user model?

Tags: python, django, backend

So I have been trying to customize the user model of my django program, my model.py looks like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your models here.


class customer_base_manager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username,firstname, lastname, password, contact, **other_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Please provide email")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user  = self.model(email=email, username=username, firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname, password=password,contact=contact, **other_fields)
        print(password)
        user.set_password(password)
        print(password)
        user.save()
        return user
    def create_superuser(self, email, username,firstname, lastname, password, contact, **other_fields):
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', False)
        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must assign is_staff = True')
        
        return self.create_user(email, username, firstname, lastname, password, contact, **other_fields)



class customer(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email           = models.EmailField(_("email"),unique=True, blank=False)
    username       = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    firstname       = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    lastname       = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False)
    start_date      = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    about           = models.TextField(_("about me"), max_length=500, blank=True)
    investing_style = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(3)])
    contact         = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,validators=[MinValueValidator(9000000001), MaxValueValidator(9999999999)])
    is_active       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff        = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = customer_base_manager()
    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'contact']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

and it worked after `makemigrations` and `migrate` I am also able to create super user here after `createsuperuser`

[image: As you can see I actually printed the inputted password so I can really check it]

As you can see I actually printed the inputted password so I can really check it

the only thing is that when I actually tried those credentials I am not actually entering the admin interface I am not really logging in the admin interface

[image]

[image]

I really wanted to surrender now can someone tell me whats happening? Here is my settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for finbot project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# print("hey => ",BASE_DIR)

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecurey-^kl(js@#3vv-!o&@q^%rget%oh2=^#u0d5b-y*i()@yo-kew3h'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products',
    'dashboard',
    'pages',
    'users',
    # third party
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'finbot.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "dashboard/templates"),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "products/templates"),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'finbot.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.customer'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not fire up a shell and retrieve an instance of your user:

```
c = customer.objects.get(email="somest...")
```

Then check all the attributes. I feel like

```
other_fields.setdefault('is_active', False)
```

is a problem here. The user needs to be active in order to get access.

Comment: yes other_fields.setdefault('is_active', False) it was the problem